# Foreign Object References / Multi-Object Commits

Tags: java, mongodb, javers

First off, JaVers looks like a great product, so thanks to all those who contribute to it.

But before my team commits to it, we are curious what support or patterns it offers for grouping changes to documents in multiple collections.

Imagine the following domain models:

```
class User {
    String username;
    List<String> roles;
}

class Role {
    String id;
    List<String> permissions;   
}
```

In order to get the change log for both a specific user, and the associated roles, I can imagine this "manual-ish" strategy:

```
UserEntity targetUser = null; // Assume valid user
Changes userChanges = javers.findChanges(byInstanceId(targetUser.getId(), UserEntity.class).build());

List<Changes> roleChanges = targetUser.getRoles().stream()
        .map(role -> javers.findChanges(byInstanceId(role.getContextId(), RoleEntity.class)
                .from(targetUser.getCreateTime())
                .build()))
        .collect(toList());

// Manually merge these two sets of changes.
```

Is this the best we can do or are there other patterns/hooks for grouping changes between models, particularly those with a "foreign object id" as part of their document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this model:

```
class User {
    String username;
    List<Role> roles;
}

class Role {
    String id;
    List<String> permissions;   
}
```

Then, you could use Shadow queries to read Users with Roles. See https://javers.org/blog/2017/12/javers-vs-envers-comparision.html#reconstructing-full-object-graphs

Comment: Shadows are just old snapshots right? I'm trying to get the change-log of an entity and it's referenced entities.

Comment: Shadows are not old Snapshots. Shadows are old versions of your domain onjects. First, you need to decide if your Role is Entity or ValueObject or maybe Value?